# Legal aspects of using logos from a LaTeX package in resume

Tags: trademark, branding

I was thinking about using Skype and LinkedIn logos from `fontawesome` package to provide corresponding contact details in my resume. But I am not sure if I am violating any rules. Can anyone throw some light over this? Should I use them or not?

Following is how a portion(at 800% zoom) of my (planned, not finalized) resume looks. Please indicate in yes/no/(any other explanation) whether the logos appear in an appropriate manner.

[image]